# strongSwan 5.6.2 and xl2tp 1.3.12 on Ubuntu 18.04 SA established but no traffic

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, strongswan, l2tp, xl2tpd

Since updating strongSwan and xl2tpd to the latest versions available for Ubuntu I encounter a problem with ESP and AH in L2TP.

Server config:

```
Interface for generating traffic

ens224: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.219.1 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 192.168.219.3

ppp0 interface created by xl2tpd

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.231.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 destination 192.168.231.2
```

Client config:

```
Interface for generating traffic

ens224: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.219.5 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 192.168.219.7

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.231.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 destination 192.168.231.1
```

when i start to ping from client to server [192.168.219.5 -> 192.168.219.1] on client i have 100% loss.

tcpdump from client side for IPSec ESP:

```
11:53:39.729306 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 27, length 64
11:53:39.735978 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.219.1 > 192.168.231.2: ICMP echo reply, id 8318, seq 27, length 64
11:54:07.956148 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 938: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:54:07.967355 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 82: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:54:07.973795 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1130: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:54:07.992232 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 531: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:54:08.017478 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:54:08.017518 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1264: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:54:08.042533 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:54:08.042751 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 992: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:54:08.773279 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 168: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: ESP(spi=0xca9bd294,seq=0x1), length 132
11:54:09.796992 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 168: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: ESP(spi=0xca9bd294,seq=0x2), length 132
```

tcpdump from server side for IPSec ESP

```
11:53:40.661518 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 27, length 64
11:53:40.661547 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.219.1 > 192.168.231.2: ICMP echo reply, id 8318, seq 27, length 64
11:54:08.892269 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 938: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:54:08.893831 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 82: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:54:08.907962 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1130: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:54:08.918575 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 531: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:54:08.952164 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:54:08.952427 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1264: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:54:08.968649 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:54:08.968759 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 992: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:54:09.705686 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 168: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: ESP(spi=0xca9bd294,seq=0x1), length 132
11:54:09.705686 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 8.0.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 56, length 64
11:54:10.729687 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 168: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: ESP(spi=0xca9bd294,seq=0x2), length 132
11:54:10.729687 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 8.0.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 57, length 64
```

Switching to IPSec AH:

Client:

```
11:56:45.057757 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 938: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:56:45.068383 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 82: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:56:45.075626 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1130: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:56:45.095453 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 531: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:56:45.117129 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:56:45.117185 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1264: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:56:45.142557 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:56:45.142567 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 976: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:56:45.309776 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x1): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 209, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
11:56:46.340981 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x2): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 210, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
11:56:47.364966 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x3): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 211, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
```

Server:

```
11:56:45.999222 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 938: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:56:46.000323 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 82: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:56:46.016453 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1130: 192.168.231.2.500 > 192.168.231.1.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
11:56:46.027356 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 531: 192.168.231.1.500 > 192.168.231.2.500: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]
11:56:46.059588 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:56:46.059840 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1264: 192.168.231.2.4500 > 192.168.231.1.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[I]
11:56:46.074470 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1296: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:56:46.074522 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 976: 192.168.231.1.4500 > 192.168.231.2.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa ikev2_auth[R]
11:56:46.249345 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x1): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 209, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
11:56:46.249345 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 8.0.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 209, length 64
11:56:47.280994 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x2): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 210, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)
11:56:47.280994 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 8.0.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 210, length 64
11:56:48.305921 In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 148: 192.168.231.2 > 192.168.231.1: AH(spi=0xc140b026,seq=0x3): 192.168.219.5 > 192.168.219.1: ICMP echo request, id 8318, seq 211, length 64 (ipip-proto-4)


[lns L2TPserver]
ip range = 192.168.231.2 - 192.168.231.254
local ip = 192.168.231.1
require chap = no
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = no
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
lac = 88.134.0.0 - 88.134.254.254
lac = 100.70.0.0 - 100.70.254.254



[lac L2TPserver]
;lns = 192.168.21.33
lns = 100.80.1.252
redial = yes
redial timeout = 5
local ip = 192.168.231.2
require chap = no
require authentication = no
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd.client
require pap = no
autodial = yes
name = cpe
length bit = yes
```

IPSec conf on server

```
keyexchange=ikev2
auto=add
left=%any
leftid=192.168.231.1
leftsubnet=192.168.219.0/30
leftcert=vpnHostCert_192.168.231.1.der
leftsendcert=always
right=%any
rightcert=VPNclientESPL2TPCert.der
rightsourceip=192.168.219.5/32
rightsubnet=192.168.219.4/30
mobike=no
```

IPSec conf on client

```
conn l2tp-ikev2-rw-esp
right=192.168.231.1
rightid=%192.168.231.1
rightsubnet=192.168.219.0/30
rightauth=pubkey
leftsourceip=%config
leftauth=pubkey
leftcert=VPNclientESPL2TPCert.der
leftsubnet=192.168.219.4/30
auto=start
```

Client

```
root@vsrv-bicab-2u:/home/VPN# ip ro get 192.168.219.1
192.168.219.1 via 192.168.231.1 dev ppp0 table 220 src 192.168.219.5 uid 0
cache
```

Server

```
root@vsrv-bicab-1u:/home/VPN# ip ro get 192.168.219.5
192.168.219.5 via 192.168.231.2 dev ppp0 table 220 src 192.168.219.1 uid 0
cache
```

Problem is that 8.0.219.x which was not the case before the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in Linux kernel 4.15, which Ubuntu 18.04 ships, that causes the IP address to change in this way.

It was caused by [5efec5c655dd](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5efec5c655dd) ("xfrm: Fix eth_hdr(skb)->h_proto to reflect inner IP version") and was later fixed with [87cdf3148b11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=87cdf3148b11) ("xfrm: Verify MAC header exists before overwriting eth_hdr(skb)->h_proto"), which was part of the 4.16 kernel sources.

This fix has apparently never been backported to 4.15 (it's not part of the [linux-4.15.y](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?h=linux-4.15.y) stable branch) and the Ubuntu kernel package maintainers didn't add it either. You might want to notify kernel devs about the missing backport to stable (via [netdev mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#netdev)) and/or [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/%2Bsource/linux) with the Ubuntu devs.

Comment: I have upgraded ubuntu kernel 4.17

root@vsrv-bicab-1u:~# uname -rs
Linux 4.17.0-041700-generic

and this seems to solve the problem, traffic is not translated to 8.0.x.x anymore.

Comment: I have reported the issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1795653

Also a test kernel has been built:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1795653/

If anyone is able to test it because I will be out of office until next week.

Comment: The fix has been released with the [4.15.0-39.42 kernel package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/linux).